# What structure to use in database for virtual file system?

Tags: sql, mysql, filesystems

I want to make a webapplication in witch there will be some users with different projects (like c project, c++ project so on). My question is that how should I build up my 3 tables: users,projects,files? One user can have many projects (there will be shared projects too), the projects can have folders(packages) and files, but on the file system I don't want to make that folder hierarchy only pointers to the specific file from database.

I.e. I am user1 and I have project1 with 3 folders in it: headers,resource,source and in each folder or root there are several files. The thing is I want to get all the project-related data from user1 and put it in a tree-view, but on the server all the files are in the same folder with randomly generated names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a structure like the one below.

Alternatively you could store your files within the database in some sort of `BLOB` (`MEDIUMBLOB`).

```
users
  id
  name
  ...

projects
  id
  name
  ...

user_projects
  user_id
  project_id

folders
  id
  name
  project_id
  parent_folder_id
  ...

files
  id
  filename
  parent_folder_id
  name_in_filesystem
  ...
```

You have a list of `users`, and a list of `projects`. The `user_project` table allows you to assign several users to a project, and to assign several projects to a user.

Every `folder` belongs to one project, and can have a `parent_folder_id` to allow hierarchies. Every file has a `parent_folder_id`, which is the reference to the folder that contains it. The `name_in_filesystem` is the random name that you use to store the file.

Comment: Good answer, do store the files in your database, otherwise you might have problems with your files being out of sync with your database if something goes wrong during a change.

Comment: Good answer, however no sub-folders supported.

Comment: @NorbertBoros Sorry if I misunderstood your comment, but `folders.parent_folder_id` would be used to create a hierarchical structure of folders.

Comment: Ok, But lets assume that a usecase requires file /foo/bar/zoo/etc/MyFile.txt.
How could we fetch this? How would the sql query look like? Can this be done in a single query or should we fire multiple ones?

Comment: @AlkisMavridis: You would ideally do that with a hierarchical query. There are already lots of examples out there, this is an answer for MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33737203/17343