# How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I have a MySQL table which is as follows:

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19 | category1 | 0 |
| 20 | category2 | 19 |
| 21 | category3 | 20 |
| 22 | category4 | 21 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Now, I want to have a single MySQL query to which I simply supply the id [for instance say `id=19`] then I should get all its child ids [i.e. result should have ids '20,21,22']....

The hierarchy of the children is not known; it can vary....

I know how to do it using a `for` loop... but how to achieve the same using a single MySQL query?

Comment: Suppose the hierarchy is 7 levels deep. What do you expect the output table to look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: MYSQL 8.0 will support Recursive query using CTE (Common Table Expressions)

Answer (score 658):

For **MySQL 8+:** use the recursive [`with`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) syntax.
For **MySQL 5.x:** use inline variables, path IDs, or self-joins.

## MySQL 8+

```
with recursive cte (id, name, parent_id) as (
  select     id,
             name,
             parent_id
  from       products
  where      parent_id = 19
  union all
  select     p.id,
             p.name,
             p.parent_id
  from       products p
  inner join cte
          on p.parent_id = cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```

The value specified in `parent_id = 19` should be set to the `id` of the parent you want to select all the descendants of.

## MySQL 5.x

For MySQL versions that do not support Common Table Expressions (up to version 5.7), you would achieve this with the following query:

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from products
         order by parent_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '19') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d74210/1).

Here, the value specified in `@pv := '19'` should be set to the `id` of the parent you want to select all the descendants of.

This will work also if a parent has *multiple* children. However, it is required that each record fulfills the condition `parent_id < id`, otherwise the results will not be complete.

#### Variable assignments inside a query

This query uses specific MySQL syntax: variables are assigned and modified during its execution. Some assumptions are made about the order of execution:

- The `from` clause is evaluated first. So that is where `@pv` gets initialised.
- The `where` clause is evaluated for each record in the order of retrieval from the `from` aliases. So this is where a condition is put to only include records for which the parent was already identified as being in the descendant tree (all descendants of the primary parent are progressively added to `@pv`).
- The conditions in this `where` clause are evaluated in order, and the evaluation is interrupted once the total outcome is certain. Therefore the second condition must be in second place, as it adds the `id` to the parent list, and this should only happen if the `id` passes the first condition. The `length` function is only called to make sure this condition is always true, even if the `pv` string would for some reason yield a falsy value.

All in all, one may find these assumptions too risky to rely on. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) warns:

> you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed [...] the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

So even though it works consistently with the above query, the evaluation order may still change, for instance when you add conditions or use this query as a view or sub-query in a larger query. It is a "feature" that [will be removed in a future MySQL release](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html):

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a user variable in statements other than `SET`. This functionality is supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to removal in a future release of MySQL.

As stated above, from MySQL 8.0 onward you should use the recursive `with` syntax.

#### Efficiency

For very large data sets this solution might get slow, as the [`find_in_set`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) operation is not the most ideal way to find a number in a list, certainly not in a list that reaches a size in the same order of magnitude as the number of records returned.

### Alternative 1: `with recursive`, `connect by`

More and more databases implement the [SQL:1999 ISO standard `WITH [RECURSIVE]` syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999#Common_table_expressions_and_recursive_queries) for recursive queries (e.g. [Postgres 8.4+](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html), [SQL Server 2005+](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-db2connectby/), [Oracle 11gR2+](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#sthref6733), [SQLite 3.8.4+](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html), [Firebird 2.1+](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-select.html#langrefupd21-select-cte), [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries), [HyperSQL 2.1.0+](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_with_clause), [Teradata](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1146_111A/ch01.032.066.html), [MariaDB 10.2.2+](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/with/)). And as of [version 8.0, also MySQL supports it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html). See the top of this answer for the syntax to use.

Some databases have an alternative, non-standard syntax for hierarchical look-ups, such as the `CONNECT BY` clause available on [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm), [DB2](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-db2connectby/), [Informix](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2035.htm), [CUBRID](https://www.cubrid.org/manual/en/10.0/sql/query/hq.html) and other databases.

MySQL version 5.7 does not offer such a feature. When your database engine provides this syntax or you can migrate to one that does, then that is certainly the best option to go for. If not, then also consider the following alternatives.

### Alternative 2: Path-style Identifiers

Things become a lot easier if you would assign `id` values that contain the hierarchical information: a path. For example, in your case this could look like this:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 19 | category1 |
| 19/1 | category2 |
| 19/1/1 | category3 |
| 19/1/1/1 | category4 |

Then your `select` would look like this:

```
select  id,
        name 
from    products
where   id like '19/%'
```

### Alternative 3: Repeated Self-joins

If you know an upper limit for how deep your hierarchy tree can become, you can use a standard `sql` query like this:

```
select      p6.parent_id as parent6_id,
            p5.parent_id as parent5_id,
            p4.parent_id as parent4_id,
            p3.parent_id as parent3_id,
            p2.parent_id as parent2_id,
            p1.parent_id as parent_id,
            p1.id as product_id,
            p1.name
from        products p1
left join   products p2 on p2.id = p1.parent_id 
left join   products p3 on p3.id = p2.parent_id 
left join   products p4 on p4.id = p3.parent_id  
left join   products p5 on p5.id = p4.parent_id  
left join   products p6 on p6.id = p5.parent_id
where       19 in (p1.parent_id, 
                   p2.parent_id, 
                   p3.parent_id, 
                   p4.parent_id, 
                   p5.parent_id, 
                   p6.parent_id) 
order       by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7;
```

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5de2a/46)

The `where` condition specifies which parent you want to retrieve the descendants of. You can extend this query with more levels as needed.

Comment: The `This will work also if a parent has multiple children.` part, where do I have to put that `parent_id < id`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Avión, it is not something you have to put somewhere, it is a *requirement* that for all records this condition is true. If you have one or more records where `parent_id > id` then you cannot use this solution.

Comment: I see. thanks. One little question. The first solution (the fist code) you're giving works perfectly, but if you have a depth more of 3 it doesnt get the childs. Do you know any way to make it work with a depth more of 3 levels? The last query works with more of 3 levels, but it's a bit more `dirty`. Thanks!

Comment: The first solution should work with any level. Can you make a fiddle that illustrates the problem you have with it? I will be happy to look at it.

Comment: @Avión, see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5de2a/1) which has levels up to 5.

Comment: I see, I think it's the problem of the `parent_id > id` :(

Comment: In that case, you could consider rebuilding your data completely with newly generated keys -- if that is a possibility for you.

Comment: @trincot Would it be possible to alter this to work in "reverse"? So grab all of a rows parents, grandparents, etc? I've used your first query for getting descendants but I would like to get the ancestors? as well.

Comment: Yes that would be possible and easier. If you get the logic used in this answer, it should not be hard to do that. Ask a new question if you bump into a problem.

Comment: @trincot got it! haha thank you again for the post it was extremely helpful.

Comment: thanks @trincot this really worked for me and good piece of work done by you.

Comment: For anyone looking to use the `WITH RECURSIVE` method, I found [the following article](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-1-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes-part-four-depth-first-or-breadth-first-traversal-transitive-closure-cycle-avoidance/) really helpful with different scenarios such as recursion depth, distincts, and detecting and closing cycles

Comment: if anyone else was looking for the answer to the question @shreddish asked, the solution is to change `on p.parent_id = cte.id` to `on p.id = cte.parent_id`

Comment: The first solution is not work for LEVEL with parent where parentID is null or 0. Here is my solution that I am trying to add LEVEL in query.

`select items_sorted.*, @pv := concat(@pv, ',', itemID),
   @lv as 'level',@parent
 from    (select * from mst_item   
    order by parentID, itemID) items_sorted,
   (select @pv := 16, @lv := 0,@parent:=0) initialisation
 where   find_in_set(parentID, @pv) > 0
    and IF(@parent<>parentID,@lv:=@lv+1,@lv=@lv)    
    and IF(@parent<>parentID,@parent:=parentID,@parent:=@parent)`

can you help me on this?

Comment: @trincot  While using this with vb.net code this query is not returning expected result

Comment: @sumil, the query is executed by mysql, not vb.net. If you have a reproducible example, you should probably ask a new question, providing the table structure, sample data, the query, its oitput for that sample and the expected output.

Comment: @trincot and how can we retrieve parents from any child element. Above query is giving as expected result.

Comment: @DharmendraSingh, read the comments above. Have a try. If you bump into a problem, ask a new question.

Comment: Is there a way you can UNION the result of the last query without using temp tables?

Comment: @ChristianGoetze, I see no reason why not. Have a go at it and when you bump into a specific issue, I would suggest asking a new question about that.

Comment: Can anyone explain how to add where clause with second query(Before MySql 8) ? I want to remove editor usertype from result set but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Pre-8 MySQL documentation explicitly says not to read & write the same variable in the same select statement. It then happens to say some vague stuff in implemention terms but does not coherently describe any syntax & behaviour that can be relied on. There is no justification for your code reading & writing the same variable. (People at Percona have shown by examining the code for particular versions that there is a certain safe idiom using case expressions.)

Comment: @philipxy, that is absolutely right, and I have already quoted the documentation on that. If you know of more explicit statements in the documentation, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, is there a way to limit results?

Comment: implementing both solutions in a framework and checking the mysql-version for the required switch: I'd suppose the mysql-server version is most important and the client-version less, is that correct? (I read when using AWS it's common that client and server versions can differ)

Comment: This worked for me for getting parents using SQL<8: `select  id,
        name,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from categories
         order by parent_id desc, id desc) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := 73671) initialisation
where   find_in_set(id, @pv)
and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', coalesce(parent_id, '')));`

Comment: In alternative 3, what does `order by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7;` mean?

Comment: It is the *position* of the column to sort by. See [Syntax description of `select` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html): `ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}`

Comment: The MySQL 5.x version is better than you think, because it returns all resulates. My test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea9a64/1

Comment: @trincot I don't know why exactly each record has to fulfill the condition `parent_id < id` at MySQL <= 5.7. My 2 cents are the following, some kind of optimization from the MySQL/MariaDB engine side which takes the rows from the sub-query in their insertion order (in other words in their ID ASC order) not the order we provided in the sub-query. But if we limit the rows inside the sub-query with WHERE condition(s), then they will be processed by the order we provided and the result will be good, doesn't count whether the `parent_id > id` or not. What do you think? Is my perception correct?

Comment: A little addition to my previous comment. It works once, it doesn't another time. Maybe it works if the table is big enough. Anyway, it isn't a reliable solution.

Answer (score 92):

From the blog **[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)**

Table structure

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS';
```

Output

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
| lev1        | lev2                 | lev3         | lev4  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | TUBE         | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | LCD          | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | PLASMA       | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | MP3 PLAYERS  | FLASH |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | CD PLAYERS   | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | 2 WAY RADIOS | NULL  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
```

Most users at one time or another have dealt with hierarchical data in a SQL database and no doubt learned that the management of hierarchical data is not what a relational database is intended for. The tables of a relational database are not hierarchical (like XML), but are simply a flat list. Hierarchical data has a parent-child relationship that is not naturally represented in a relational database table.
[Read more](https://web.archive.org/web/20181221162916/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Refer the blog for more details.

**EDIT:**

```
select @pv:=category_id as category_id, name, parent from category
join
(select @pv:=19)tmp
where parent=@pv
```

Output:

```
category_id name    parent
19  category1   0
20  category2   19
21  category3   20
22  category4   21
```

Reference: [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in Mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: That blog is a nice tutorial for Hierarchical Data in MySQL. I do't know how much it will be useful in your case. Try it.. all the best :)

Comment: That's fine as long as there are no more than 4 levels at most in the hierarchy. If there are N levels, you have to know that to create the query properly.

Comment: @Damodaran,

Thanks for your reply...

What I needed is a condition where the number of childs are not known... and in the blog that is using a inner join concept in that the hierarchy is required to be known which is not in my case... so let me know your view  on the same... So, in simple words I need a query to handle 'n' hirerachy levels where 'n' is not known.....

Comment: @user3036105 Refer this link http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/

AND

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql

Comment: @user3036105: it is not possible to do this in MySQL with a *single* SQL query. MySQL simply isn't advanced enough for that. If you really need this, consider upgrading to a DBMS which supports recursive queries.

Comment: a nice reference [The Performance of Traversing a SQL Hierarchy](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-performance-of-traversing-a-sql-hierarchy-/)

Comment: >Most users at one time or another have dealt with hierarchical data in a SQL database and no doubt learned that the management of hierarchical data is not what a relational database is intended for. Maybe you meant a MySQL database. An Oracle database handles hierarchical data and queries quite well.

Comment: Thank you @Damodaran for the idea! ;)

Comment: "...the management of hierarchical data is not what a relational database is intended for..." While this may have not been the original intention of a relational database, in the real-world hierarchical data is incredibly commonplace and MySQL should reflect how people actually need to use their data in real-world scenarios.

Comment: Pictures of tables are 'flat'. Tables represent multidimensional relationships. That includes hierarchical relationships. It is DBMSs that don't supply relational support for that special case that are the problem, not the relational model.

Comment: If you have to hardcode the number of levels it recursed into, it is not recursion.

Comment: The Mike Hillyer site has gone away. Looks like he's moved his article behind a paywall at https://www.scribd.com/document/48207958/Managing-Hierarchical-Data-in-MySQL

Comment: Still not supported natively by MySQL?

Answer (score 20):

Try these:

Table definition:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS category;
CREATE TABLE category (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    parent_id INT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_category_parent FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
    REFERENCES category (id)
) engine=innodb;
```

Experimental rows:

```
INSERT INTO category VALUES
(19, 'category1', NULL),
(20, 'category2', 19),
(21, 'category3', 20),
(22, 'category4', 21),
(23, 'categoryA', 19),
(24, 'categoryB', 23),
(25, 'categoryC', 23),
(26, 'categoryD', 24);
```

Recursive Stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getpath;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE getpath(IN cat_id INT, OUT path TEXT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE catname VARCHAR(20);
    DECLARE temppath TEXT;
    DECLARE tempparent INT;
    SET max_sp_recursion_depth = 255;
    SELECT name, parent_id FROM category WHERE id=cat_id INTO catname, tempparent;
    IF tempparent IS NULL
    THEN
        SET path = catname;
    ELSE
        CALL getpath(tempparent, temppath);
        SET path = CONCAT(temppath, '/', catname);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Wrapper function for the stored procedure:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getpath;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getpath(cat_id INT) RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE res TEXT;
    CALL getpath(cat_id, res);
    RETURN res;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Select example:

```
SELECT id, name, getpath(id) AS path FROM category;
```

Output:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
| id | name      | path                                    |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
| 19 | category1 | category1                               |
| 20 | category2 | category1/category2                     |
| 21 | category3 | category1/category2/category3           |
| 22 | category4 | category1/category2/category3/category4 |
| 23 | categoryA | category1/categoryA                     |
| 24 | categoryB | category1/categoryA/categoryB           |
| 25 | categoryC | category1/categoryA/categoryC           |
| 26 | categoryD | category1/categoryA/categoryB/categoryD |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Filtering rows with certain path:

```
SELECT id, name, getpath(id) AS path FROM category HAVING path LIKE 'category1/category2%';
```

Output:

```
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
| id | name      | path                                    |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
| 20 | category2 | category1/category2                     |
| 21 | category3 | category1/category2/category3           |
| 22 | category4 | category1/category2/category3/category4 |
+----+-----------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This won't work for more then one child. e.g `(20, 'category2', 19),
(21, 'category3', 20),
(22, 'category4', 20),`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works for more than one child. I even tested it again.

Comment: @Fandi Susanto , Thanks it alote helps me.

Comment: The solution worked for my but it is important to check if the top level parents (categories) are identified by a parent_id which is NULL or 0. Accordingly, the tempparent check must look like:
`IF (tempparent IS NULL OR tempparent = 0)`

Comment: Thanks man ! worked well for me
had just to change `IF tempparent IS NULL` to `IF tempparent = 0` in my case

Answer (score 16):

Did the same thing for another quetion here

[Mysql select recursive get all child with multiple level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363893/mysql-select-recursive-get-all-child-with-multiple-level/28366310)

The query will be :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
  SELECT @pv:=(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM table WHERE parent_id IN (@pv)
  ) AS lv FROM table 
  JOIN
  (SELECT @pv:=1)tmp
  WHERE parent_id IN (@pv)
) a;
```

Comment: How can we do this? 

`SELECT idFolder, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(lv SEPARATOR ',') FROM ( SELECT @pv:=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idFolder SEPARATOR ',') FROM Folder WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) AS lv FROM Folder JOIN (SELECT @pv:= F1.idFolder )tmp WHERE idFolderParent IN (@pv)) a) from folder F1 where id > 10`;

I can't refer F1.idFolder for @pv

Comment: I recreated the table from OP's original question with the data as shown in their comment, then ran your query here, and got a single `NULL` as a result. Do you know why that could be? Are there prerequisites in terms of the database engine, or has something changed since you made this answer that makes this query outdated?

Answer (score 12):

If you need quick read speed, the best option is to use a closure table. A closure table contains a row for each ancestor/descendant pair. So in your example, the closure table would look like

```
ancestor | descendant | depth
0        | 0          | 0
0        | 19         | 1
0        | 20         | 2
0        | 21         | 3
0        | 22         | 4
19       | 19         | 0
19       | 20         | 1
19       | 21         | 3
19       | 22         | 4
20       | 20         | 0
20       | 21         | 1
20       | 22         | 2
21       | 21         | 0
21       | 22         | 1
22       | 22         | 0
```

Once you have this table, hierarchical queries become very easy and fast. To get all the descendants of category 20:

```
SELECT cat.* FROM categories_closure AS cl
INNER JOIN categories AS cat ON cat.id = cl.descendant
WHERE cl.ancestor = 20 AND cl.depth > 0
```

Of course, there is a big downside whenever you use denormalized data like this. You need to maintain the closure table alongside your categories table. The best way is probably to use triggers, but it is somewhat complex to correctly track inserts/updates/deletes for closure tables. As with anything, you need to look at your requirements and decide what approach is best for you.

**Edit**: See the question [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database) for more options. There are different optimal solutions for different situations.

Answer (score 12):

Based on the @trincot answer, very good explained, I use `WITH RECURSIVE ()` statement to **create a breadcrumb** using `id` of the current page and **go backwards in the hierarchy** to find the every `parent` in my `route` table.

So, the @trincot solution is adapted here in the opposite direction to find parents instead of descendants.

I also added `depth` value which is usefull to invert result order (otherwise the breadcrumb would be upside down).

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (
    `id`,
    `title`,
    `url`,
    `icon`,
    `class`,
    `parent_id`,
    `depth`
) AS (
    SELECT   
        `id`,
        `title`,
        `url`,
        `icon`,
        `class`,
        `parent_id`,
        1 AS `depth` 
    FROM     `route`
    WHERE    `id` = :id
      
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        P.`id`,
        P.`title`,
        P.`url`,
        P.`icon`,
        P.`class`,
        P.`parent_id`,
        `depth` + 1
    FROM `route` P
        
    INNER JOIN cte
        ON P.`id` = cte.`parent_id`
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY `depth` DESC;
```

> Before upgrade to mySQL 8+, **I was using vars but it's deprecated and no more working on my 8.0.22 version** !

**EDIT 2021-02-19** :
**Example for hierarchical menu**

After @david comment I decided to try to make a full hierarchical menu with all nodes and sorted as I want (with `sorting` column which sort items in each depth). Very usefull for my user/authorization matrix page.

*This really simplifies my old version with one query on each depth (PHP loops)*.

[image: ERP authroization Matrix]

This example intergrates an INNER JOIN with `url` table to filter route by website (multi-websites CMS system).

You can see the essential `path` column that contains `CONCAT()` function to sort the menu in the right way.

```
SELECT R.* FROM (
    WITH RECURSIVE cte (
        `id`,
        `title`,
        `url`,
        `icon`,
        `class`,
        `parent`,
        `depth`,
        `sorting`,
        `path`
    ) AS (
        SELECT 
            `id`,
            `title`,
            `url`,
            `icon`,
            `class`,
            `parent`,
            1 AS `depth`,
            `sorting`,
            CONCAT(`sorting`, ' ' , `title`) AS `path`
        FROM `route`
        WHERE `parent` = 0
        UNION ALL SELECT 
            D.`id`,
            D.`title`,
            D.`url`,
            D.`icon`,
            D.`class`,
            D.`parent`,
            `depth` + 1,
            D.`sorting`,
            CONCAT(cte.`path`, ' > ', D.`sorting`, ' ' , D.`title`)
        FROM `route` D
        INNER JOIN cte
            ON cte.`id` = D.`parent`
    )
    SELECT * FROM cte
) R

INNER JOIN `url` U
    ON R.`id` = U.`route_id`
    AND U.`site_id` = 1

ORDER BY `path` ASC
```

Comment: I used it for a useful comment with breadcrumb-path but it could be used for a menu too. Thanks! btw. I use this additional to the solution from @trincot

Comment: Yes @David for multi-level menu without predefined depth, we could use it, didn't think of it, thanks.

Comment: I just remark your edit, thanks for the credit ;-) You might be interested in this discussion: https://gist.github.com/DavidBruchmann/cf27eb309e48e0df326b3bafce2b30e3

Comment: Great sub-subquery for nested parent-child nodes.

Answer (score 11):

The best approach I've come up with is

1. Use lineage to store\sort\trace trees. That's more than enough, and works thousands times faster for reading than any other approach.
   It also allows to stay on that pattern even if DB will change(as ANY db will allow that pattern to be used)
2. Use function that determines lineage for specific ID.
3. Use it as you wish (in selects, or on CUD operations, or even by jobs).

Lineage approach descr. can be found wherever, for example
[Here](http://ferdychristant.com/blog/archive/DOMM-7QJPM7) or [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30021/mysql-tree-hierarchical-query).
As of function - [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948009/finding-all-parents-in-mysql-table-with-single-query) is what enspired me.

In the end - got more-or-less simple, relatively fast, and SIMPLE solution.

Function's body

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `get_lineage`(the_id INT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

 DECLARE v_rec INT DEFAULT 0;

 DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
 DECLARE v_res text DEFAULT '';
 DECLARE v_papa int;
 DECLARE v_papa_papa int DEFAULT -1;
 DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR 
  select _id,parent_id -- @n:=@n+1 as rownum,T1.* 
  from 
    (SELECT @r AS _id,
        (SELECT @r := table_parent_id FROM table WHERE table_id = _id) AS parent_id,
        @l := @l + 1 AS lvl
    FROM
        (SELECT @r := the_id, @l := 0,@n:=0) vars,
        table m
    WHERE @r <> 0
    ) T1
    where T1.parent_id is not null
 ORDER BY T1.lvl DESC;
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open csr;
    read_loop: LOOP
    fetch csr into v_papa,v_papa_papa;
        SET v_rec = v_rec+1;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        -- add first
        IF v_rec = 1 THEN
            SET v_res = v_papa_papa;
        END IF;
        SET v_res = CONCAT(v_res,'-',v_papa);
    END LOOP;
    close csr;
    return v_res;
END
```

And then you just

```
select get_lineage(the_id)
```

Hope it helps somebody :)

Answer (score 7):

Something not mentioned here, although a bit similar to the second alternative of the accepted answer but different and low cost for big hierarchy query and easy (insert update delete) items, would be  adding a persistent path  column for each item.

some like:

```
id | name        | path
19 | category1   | /19
20 | category2   | /19/20
21 | category3   | /19/20/21
22 | category4   | /19/20/21/22
```

Example:

```
-- get children of category3:
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE path LIKE '/19/20/21%'
-- Reparent an item:
UPDATE my_table SET path = REPLACE(path, '/19/20', '/15/16') WHERE path LIKE '/19/20/%'
```

**Optimise the path length and `ORDER BY path` using base36 encoding instead real numeric path id**

```
 // base10 => base36
 '1' => '1',
 '10' => 'A',
 '100' => '2S',
 '1000' => 'RS',
 '10000' => '7PS',
 '100000' => '255S',
 '1000000' => 'LFLS',
 '1000000000' => 'GJDGXS',
 '1000000000000' => 'CRE66I9S'
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36

Suppressing also the slash '/' separator by using fixed length and padding to the encoded id

Detailed optimization explanation here:
https://bojanz.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/storing-hierarchical-data-materialized-path/

**TODO**

building a function or procedure to split path for retreive ancestors of one item

Comment: @MTK, can we get the result by DESC like getting the latest replies from a post comment?

Comment: @LikiCrus I use that for hierarchical queries. If you want order by latest replies I think you must play with date of the comments. Example. `Select comment FROM comments WHERE ... (subject or user or theme or whatever condition) ... ORDER BY posting_date DESC` or playng with `GROUP BY user ODER BY posting date` take a look also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362160/mysql-order-by-inside-of-group-by

Comment: @MTK, I don't think we can get the `DESC` result with your `path` approach. Because `path` only supports ASC itself.

Comment: @LikiCrus I said before that you have to use another column for this purpose and not the path column. For example date, id, etc. The path column is used to hierarchize

Answer (score 6):

Simple query to list child's of first recursion:

```
select @pv:=id as id, name, parent_id
from products
join (select @pv:=19)tmp
where parent_id=@pv
```

Result:

```
id  name        parent_id
20  category2   19
21  category3   20
22  category4   21
26  category24  22
```

... with left join:

```
select
    @pv:=p1.id as id
  , p2.name as parent_name
  , p1.name name
  , p1.parent_id
from products p1
join (select @pv:=19)tmp
left join products p2 on p2.id=p1.parent_id -- optional join to get parent name
where p1.parent_id=@pv
```

The solution of @tincot to list all child's:

```
select  id,
        name,
        parent_id 
from    (select * from products
         order by parent_id, id) products_sorted,
        (select @pv := '19') initialisation
where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
```

Test it online with [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a318e3/4/0) and see all results.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a318e3/4/0

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this in other databases quite easily with a recursive query (YMMV on performance).

The other way to do it is to store two extra bits of data, a left and right value. The left and right value are derived from a pre-order traversal of the tree structure you're representing.

This is know as Modified Preorder Tree Traversal and lets you run a simple query to get all parent values at once. It also goes by the name "nested set".

Comment: I wanted to add a similar comment to yours, but since you did it, I will add just a link to a good example of the "nested set": http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Answer (score 4):

Just use [BlueM/tree](https://github.com/BlueM/Tree) php class for make tree of a self-relation table in mysql.

> Tree and Tree\Node are PHP classes for handling data that is structured hierarchically using parent ID references. A typical example is a table in a relational database where each record’s “parent” field references the primary key of another record. Of course, Tree cannot only use data originating from a database, but anything: you supply the data, and Tree uses it, regardless of where the data came from and how it was processed. [read more](https://github.com/BlueM/Tree/blob/master/README.markdown)

Here is an example of using BlueM/tree:

```
<?php 
require '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php'; $db = new PDO(...); // Set up your database connection 
$stm = $db->query('SELECT id, parent, title FROM tablename ORDER BY title'); 
$records = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$tree = new BlueM\Tree($records); 
...
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

It's a **category** table.

```
SELECT  id,
        NAME,
        parent_category 
FROM    (SELECT * FROM category
         ORDER BY parent_category, id) products_sorted,
        (SELECT @pv := '2') initialisation
WHERE   FIND_IN_SET(parent_category, @pv) > 0
AND     @pv := CONCAT(@pv, ',', id)
```

***Output::***
[image]

Comment: Can you explain this? But I guarantee this is working. Thank you.

Comment: plz explain the query and what is the meaning of @pv?? How loop is working in this query?

Comment: Does not seem to work on all levels if there are children that have lower IDs than their parents. :(

Comment: @Jonas took me 20 minutes to identify the actual problem, trying with different combination. yes, you're right. It'll not work with ID lower than its parent ID. Do you have any solution?

Comment: @muaaz I finally solved it using a "path" field that contains the path for the respective row, e. g. row with ID 577 has path "/1/2/45/577/". If you're looking for all children of ID 2, you can simply select all rows with path LIKE "/1/2/%". Only downside is that you have to update the paths in your update methods. But for MySQL 5.6 (compatible), it was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Seems you just copied from the top answer and changed some table and field name.

Answer (score 2):

Its a little tricky one, check this whether it is working for you

```
select a.id,if(a.parent = 0,@varw:=concat(a.id,','),@varw:=concat(a.id,',',@varw)) as list from (select * from recursivejoin order by if(parent=0,id,parent) asc) a left join recursivejoin b on (a.id = b.parent),(select @varw:='') as c  having list like '%19,%';
```

SQL fiddle link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3cdf/2

Replace with your field and table name appropriately.

Comment: It won't work in this case http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19360/2, with this trick, at least you should order by hierarchical level first.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, hope this will work for you too. It will give you a Record set Root to Child for any Specific Menu. Change the Field name as per your requirements.

```
SET @id:= '22';

SELECT Menu_Name, (@id:=Sub_Menu_ID ) as Sub_Menu_ID, Menu_ID 
FROM 
    ( SELECT Menu_ID, Menu_Name, Sub_Menu_ID 
      FROM menu 
      ORDER BY Sub_Menu_ID DESC
    ) AS aux_table 
    WHERE Menu_ID = @id
     ORDER BY Sub_Menu_ID;
```

Comment: Does not seem to work on all levels if there are children that have greater IDs than their parents

Answer (score 0):

Below Mysql query returns the child ids and the 'level of hierarchy' as well. This column will be very useful to trace the hierarchy levels from the parent.

```
select * from category;
```

[image: category table]

```
with recursive rec_cte as(    
select id, name, parent_id, 1 as hierarchy from category
where parent_id = 19
union all
select p.id, p.name, p.parent_id, hierarchy+1 from  category p
inner join rec_cte cte
where p.parent_id = cte.id
and  hierarchy +1 <= p.parent_id
)
select * 
from rec_cte
;
```

[image: recursive query result]

Answer (score -1):

I found it more easily to :

1) create a function that will check if a item is anywhere in the parent hierarchy of another one. Something like this (I will not write the function, make it with WHILE DO) :

```
is_related(id, parent_id);
```

in your example

```
is_related(21, 19) == 1;
is_related(20, 19) == 1;
is_related(21, 18) == 0;
```

2) use a sub-select , something like this:

```
select ...
from table t
join table pt on pt.id in (select i.id from table i where is_related(t.id,i.id));
```

Answer (score -2):

I have made a query for you. This will give you Recursive Category with a Single Query:

```
SELECT id,NAME,'' AS subName,'' AS subsubName,'' AS subsubsubName FROM Table1 WHERE prent is NULL
UNION 
SELECT b.id,a.name,b.name AS subName,'' AS subsubName,'' AS subsubsubName FROM Table1 AS a LEFT JOIN Table1 AS b ON b.prent=a.id WHERE a.prent is NULL AND b.name IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT c.id,a.name,b.name AS subName,c.name AS subsubName,'' AS subsubsubName FROM Table1 AS a LEFT JOIN Table1 AS b ON b.prent=a.id LEFT JOIN Table1 AS c ON c.prent=b.id WHERE a.prent is NULL AND c.name IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT d.id,a.name,b.name AS subName,c.name AS subsubName,d.name AS subsubsubName FROM Table1 AS a LEFT JOIN Table1 AS b ON b.prent=a.id LEFT JOIN Table1 AS c ON c.prent=b.id LEFT JOIN Table1 AS d ON d.prent=c.id WHERE a.prent is NULL AND d.name IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY NAME,subName,subsubName,subsubsubName
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4f997/3).